# minio client works from local but not from docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, timeout

I have set up a minio server like so:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 minio/minio server data &
```

the server works as I'm able to point my browser to http://172.17.0.2:9000 and login. If I use minio client from my console it is working too.

But I can't make it work from a docker container:

```
FROM fedora:latest

RUN mkdir /minio && \
    mkdir /minio/data

COPY ./script.sh /minio/script.sh

RUN \
    curl https://dl.min.io/client/mc/release/linux-amd64/mc > /usr/bin/mc && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/mc
```

After that i run script.sh with a very simple docker-compose configuration and i have the following error:

```
sync_1  | + mc config host add local http://172.17.0.2:9000 minioadmin minioadmin --api S3v4 --lookup auto
sync_1  | Added `local` successfully.
sync_1  | ++ mc find local/test --newer-than 2d0h0m --ignore '*.html'
sync_1  | mc: <ERROR> Unable to stat `local/test`. Get http://172.17.0.2:9000/test/?location=: dial tcp 172.17.0.2:9000: i/o timeout.
```

(sync is the name of the service in the docker compose file and the command followed after the "+" are the results of running the script with bash -x option for debbugging).

What can be the reason? The server contains only small sample files.

Comment: Where did that IP address come from?  You can’t generally directly use the Docker-internal IP addresses; [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the standard network environment.  (You probably can’t run the server container on the so-called “default bridge network” here, you must explicitly use some other `docker run --net`, or better still, launch it in the same `docker-compose.yml` file.)

Comment: @DavidMaze when I lunch the server i have a line "endpoint:  http://172.17.0.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000" among other things. If I use use http://127.0.0.1:9000 the error is "connection refused" so i guess in some way the endpoint is working (?). Use the same docker-compose file is not an option due to requirement restrictions

Comment: Curious what the work around if any was found here... @JoulinRouge

Answer (score 2):

docker-compose uses `container_name` as address, don't use docker ips directly.

If you running it with docker-compose, your minio-mc command should look like this:

```
...
mc config host add local http://minio:9000 minioadmin minioadmin --api S3v4 --lookup auto
```